# Auto vectorization in llvm

Tags: llvm, clang

I am trying to create auto-vectorized code with clang-3.2

From the slides here - http://llvm.org/devmtg/2012-04-12/Slides/Hal_Finkel.pdf

I should be able to generate vectorized code with this command line.

```
bin/clang++ -c -O3 -mllvm -vectorize -bb-vectorize-aligned-only clang-auto-vec.cpp
```

But it throws an error error: `unsupported option '-b b-vectorize-aligned-only'`

If i remove just the `-bb-vectorize-aligned-only`, it doesn't create any vectorized code.

whats going wrong here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Prepend `-mllvm` to every flag. E.g. `-mllvm -vectorize -mllvm -bb-vectorize-aligned-only`